# VBA error when creating and saving a file in a onedrive folder

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive, mkdir

I have a VBA file which creates packs to support salespeople present offers to their customers. I have a main template, but the nature of this specific sales process is that the offer could change multiple times before the customer agrees anything.

To account for these re-runs, the macro will create a folder in OneDrive, and then save itself within that folder so that it can be run without having to start afresh.

However, I am getting some errors when it gets to the below code - here is a walkthrough of the steps:

- SaveFilePath is a string which contains the target folder for whichever user is running it - i.e. [C:\Users\User.Name\Company\Output]
- It then gets some contract details added to determine the name of the folder to create for that customer - i.e. [C:\Users\User.Name\Company\Output\123 - Customer Name - Gas]
- I then use MDir to create a folder with the above path - this works
- It then saves itself within the folder it has created, with a name ending in "Master.xlsb" - this is where I am getting the issues

The process throws out this error:

> Run-time error 1004: Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

However, when I check the folder, it has successfully saved itself within the folder - i.e. it has worked, but it still throws out an error.

I have played around with some of the parameters in the SaveAs line, but still get this error. Likewise with turning alerts off - still get the same issue.

```
SaveFilePath = SaveFilePath & TenderID & " - " & wsControl.Range("CustomerName") & " - " & Utility & " " & MPAN & "\"
If Dir(SaveFilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (SaveFilePath)


'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb1.SaveAs FileName:=SaveFilePath & FileName & " Master.xlsb", ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges  'add thisback in when live
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Any help with this would be appreciated - I am banging my head against a wall with this one.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you prefix the file name with a space? " Master.xlsb"

Comment: The file name ends up as a combination between the customer name, the product and the word "Master" - like this "Test Customer - Gas Master.xlsb"

The first part of this filename comes from the variable "FileName" in the code above - forgot to specify that, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error with a slightly different scenario, so thought the info might help lead us both somewhere.

I am saving my file into an existing OneDrive folder from VBA and am getting the same error.

I noticed the filename my process creates was not C:... but was https:// (even though I was running from C:).   I'm assuming this is due to it being a OneDrive-synched folder.   I adjusted my process to account for this, but the error still occurs.

When I run the process in a non-OneDrive folder...

1. I don't get the issue
2. When the file already exists, I get a "do you want to replace" message, not an error

I'm speculating that this is some sort of OneDrive Synch delay/cleanup issue since it goes away over time.